# How to get data from multiple URL's and store it into a simple array?

Tags: android, json, url, android-asynctask, http-get

I'm using the following class (AsyncTask) to retrieve info from 8 different URL's. I want to store the retrieved data into an array of 8 elements (one for each URL I get data from).

```
 private class getDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String...urls){
        String response = "";
        for(String url : urls){
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try{
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

                String s = "";

                while((s = buffer.readLine()) != null){
                    response += s;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Resources.descriptionArray[descriptionArray_Counter] = Html.fromHtml(result).toString();
        descriptionArray_Counter++;
    }
```

And calling it like this:

```
   getDataClass getData = new getDataClass();
   getData.execute(description_links);
```

The problem I'm obviously getting is that all the info is stored into array[0], as my AsyncTask class returns a single "response" string.

What I'd like to know, since I haven't found many examples of this is what would be a more elegant way to do this and how would other, more experienced coders go about this.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 as my AsyncTask class returns a single "response" string.
```

=> It is not true. Because AsyncTask can return ArrayList as well other than a string only.

You should check the [AsyncTask's Generic type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any help about how to go about implementing this? Or a link maybe?